# Android - BroadcastReceiver's onReceive crashing from Intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

So I'm trying to start a new activity from my `onReceive` function in a `BroadcastReceiver, yet I seem to be crashing. Without further adieu here is the code:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {     

    //... other stuff that's not relevant

    Intent j = new Intent(context, myClass.class);  
    context.startActivity(j); 
    //If I comment the above two lines out and replace with a Toast, the toast shows up
}
```

Thoughts?

Edit - did some more testing, and I can start this activity from other places using the same kind of intent. I just can't do it from the `BroadcastReceiver`...

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Intent j = new Intent(context, myClass.class);
j.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(j);
```

Comment: awesome man, thanks! Just out of curiosity, in general when should I watch that I'm adding appropriate flags to my intents?

Comment: Outside of `BroadcastReceiver`s its mostly if you are looking for special behavior (and even `BroadcastReceiver`s only have this one requirement). In general you don't really need any flags. When you start trying to do special things (like have an Intent resume a running Activity or clearing a task stack) then that's when the flags come into play, but in general a quick look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html will show you what flags are available so if you come across a situation where an Intent isn't performing for you like you'd want take a look at that.