# Android Activity crashing when trying to fire Intent.ACTION_VIEW from within BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-activity, crash, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

My activity should download a file and afterwards open it by sending Intent.ACTION_VIEW. The download itself works fine, I can access it afterwards in the Downloads section.
If I'm using a DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS Intent instead of Intent.ACTION_VIEW it also works fine.

But when using **Intent.ACTION_VIEW** the activity crashes.

```
public class RESTTestDownloadActivity extends SOFAActivity {

private DownloadManager downloadManager;
private IntentFilter downloadFilter;
private BroadcastReceiver downloadReceiver;
private long downloadID;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    
    setTitle("RESTTestDownloadActivity");

    downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    
    TestGetAttachment();
}

private void TestGetAttachment(){
    
    downloadFilter = new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE); 

    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse("http://address:port/directory/testGetAttachment"));
    downloadID = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
    
    downloadReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(RESTTestDownloadActivity.this, "ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE received.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();
            query.setFilterById(downloadID);
            Cursor cursor = downloadManager.query(query);
            if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
                System.out.println("Download matches.");
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
                int status = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);
                int columnReason = cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_REASON);
                int reason = cursor.getInt(columnReason);

                if(status!=DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL){
                    System.out.println("Download != STATUS_SUCCESSFUL.");
                    AlertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Error")
                        .setMessage(reason)
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", null)
                        .show();
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Download = STATUS_SUCCESSFUL.");
                    Toast.makeText(RESTTestDownloadActivity.this, "Download successful.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Uri dlUri = Uri.parse(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI)));
                    System.out.println("Download-URI: " + dlUri.toString());
                    unregisterReceiver(downloadReceiver);
                    downloadReceiver = null;
                    // This is working perfectly fine
                    startActivity(new Intent(DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS));
                    // But this is crashing
//                  Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, dlUri);
//                  i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
//                  startActivity(i);
                }
                downloadManager.remove(downloadID);
                downloadReceiver = null;
            } 
        }
    };
    registerReceiver(downloadReceiver, downloadFilter);

}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    if(downloadReceiver!=null){
        System.out.println("Unregistering downloadReceiver...");
        unregisterReceiver(downloadReceiver);
    }
}
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    if(downloadReceiver!=null){
        System.out.println("Registering downloadReceiver...");
        registerReceiver(downloadReceiver, downloadFilter);
    }
}
```

As you can see I already tried to add the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6404397/android-broadcastreceivers-onreceive-crashing-from-intent).

LogCat does output the following:

> 08-05 13:04:35.437: INFO/System.out(2449): *.RESTTestDownloadActivity.onResume()
>
> 08-05 13:04:35.446: INFO/System.out(2449): Registering downloadReceiver...
>
> 08-05 13:04:35.846: INFO/ActivityManager(77): Displayed *.RESTTestDownloadActivity: +561ms
>
> 08-05 13:04:36.046: INFO/DownloadManager(274): Initiating request for download 24
>
> 08-05 13:04:40.956: DEBUG/dalvikvm(216): GC_EXPLICIT freed 26K, 47% free 3220K/6023K, external 6059K/7285K, paused 68ms
>
> 08-05 13:04:45.855: DEBUG/dalvikvm(157): GC_CONCURRENT freed 795K, 56% free 2872K/6471K, external 2402K/2630K, paused 10ms+15ms
>
> 08-05 13:04:46.135: INFO/System.out(2449): Download gefunden.
>
> 08-05 13:04:46.135: INFO/System.out(2449): Download = STATUS_SUCCESSFUL.
>
> 08-05 13:04:46.155: INFO/System.out(2449): Download-URI: content://downloads/my_downloads/24
>
> 08-05 13:04:46.165: INFO/ActivityManager(77): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://downloads/my_downloads/24 flg=0x10000000 } from pid 2449
>
> 08-05 13:04:46.175: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(2449): Shutting down VM
>
> 08-05 13:04:46.185: WARN/dalvikvm(2449): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
>
> 08-05 13:04:46.195: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2449): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> 08-05 13:04:46.195: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2449): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE pkg=* (has extras) } in *.RESTTestDownloadActivity$1@405376e8
>
> 08-05 13:04:46.195: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2449):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:722)
>
> 08-05 13:04:46.195: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2449):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
>
> 08-05 13:04:46.195: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2449):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>
> 08-05 13:04:46.195: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2449):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>
> 08-05 13:04:46.195: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2449):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
>
> 08-05 13:04:46.195: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2449):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>
> 08-05 13:04:46.195: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2449):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>
> 08-05 13:04:46.195: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2449):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>
> 08-05 13:04:46.195: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2449):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
>
> 08-05 13:04:46.195: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2449):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>
> 08-05 13:04:46.195: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2449): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://downloads/my_downloads/24 flg=0x10000000 }
>
> 08-05 13:04:46.195: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2449):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1409)
>
> 08-05 13:04:46.195: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2449):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
>
> 08-05 13:04:46.195: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2449):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
>
> 08-05 13:04:46.195: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2449):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
>
> 08-05 13:04:46.195: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2449):     at ***.RESTTestDownloadActivity$1.onReceive(RESTTestDownloadActivity.java:75)
>
> 08-05 13:04:46.195: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2449):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:709)
>
> 08-05 13:04:46.195: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2449):     ... 9 more
>
> 08-05 13:04:46.216: WARN/ActivityManager(77):   Force finishing activity *.RESTTestDownloadActivity
>
> 08-05 13:04:46.739: WARN/ActivityManager(77): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{408abbf0 *.RESTTestDownloadActivity}

Any idea why only Intent.ACTION_VIEW results in a crash?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://downloads/my_downloads/24 flg=0x10000000 }
```

Please add a MIME type to your `Intent`, to help Android find the appropriate activity for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try saving the file on your SD card and then firing an intent with ACTION_VIEW. For this to work, you need to set the intent data with Uri.fromFile(file_object_pointing_to_your_file) method. (Uri.parse() method will cause a crash in this case)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because You are using using `DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS` Intent instead of `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` and for `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` there is an activity in your app or any other app which can handle your view request.I mean item which you are downloading can not be opened by any activity.

SO you have either create your own activity which can open your item or you have to install external apk which can open your item.

So best choice is that you have to use `DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS`

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're telling me.
Using Intent DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS: the Downloads section opens and I can open the file manually. That means there **is** a handler for the file type.
Using Intent Intent.ACTION_VIEW: The file should be automatically opened with the matching file type handler (which actually exists). But it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException`. For me, it helped to convert the "content" URI to a "file" URI first:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI)));
if ("content".equals(uri.getScheme())) {
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[] { android.provider.MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA }, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();   
    final String filePath = cursor.getString(0);
    cursor.close();
    uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath));
}
if ("file".equals(uri.getScheme()) {
    Intent installIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    installIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // Required if launching outside of an activity
    installIntent.setDataAndType(uri, downloadManager.getMimeTypeForDownloadedFile(downloadId));
    startActivity(installIntent);
}
```